# Fixing Laravel form array validation recursion limits

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

Laravel Form Validation is great, except that it doesn't filter out extraneous keys when array notation is used.

I am type hinting the form request in my controller.

```
public function saveEdit(Post\EditRequest $request)
{
    $valid = $request->validated();
}
```

If my form has `address_1` and `address_2`, and the user spoofs `address_3`, the spoofed value will not turn up in `$valid`.

However, if my form uses array notation, such as `venue[address_1]`, and `venue[address_2]`, then the user can spoof `venue[address_3]`, and it will turn up in `$valid`.

Has anyone else come across this? How did you deal with it?

It seems like the `validated()` method on the form request class needs to operate recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Laravel doesn't include built-in support for validating array *keys* yet, only array *values*. To do so, we need to add [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules).

However, with alternative protection like `$fillable` model attributes and the `array_only()` helper function, creating these rules is a lot of extra work for a very unlikely edge case. We provide *validation feedback* for *expected* user error and *sanitize* to protect our data from *unexpected* input.

If the user spoofs a key, as long as we don't save it, or we filter it out, they won't be too concerned if they don't see a pretty validation message—it doesn't make sense to validate a field that shouldn't exist in the first place.

To illustrate how sanitization works, here's a `Venue` model that declares its fillable attributes:

```php
class Venue extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'address_1', 'address_2' ]; 
    ...
}
```

Now, if a malicious user attempts to spoof another attribute in the array:

```php
<input name="venue[address_1]" value="...">
<input name="venue[address_2]" value="...">
<input name="venue[address_3]" value="spoof!">
```

...and we use the input array directly to update a model:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $venueId)
{
    $venue = Venue::find($venueId); 
    $venue->update($request->venue);
    ...
}
```

...the model will strip out the additional `address_3` element from the input array because we never declared it as a fillable field. In other words, the model sanitized the input.

In some cases, we may need to simply sanitize array elements without using Eloquent models. We can use the `array_only()` function (or `Arr:only()`) to do this:

```php
$venueAddress = array_only($request->venue, [ 'address_1', 'address_2' ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dot notation

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'venue.address_1' => 'required',
            'venue.address_2' => 'required',
            'venue.address_3'=>'required',
        ];
    }
```

and if you are using dynamic array you can do same by

```
 public function rules()
     {
         return [
             'venue.address_.*' => 'required'
         ];
     }
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, I am using dot notation.

Comment: Can you please update your question and share you code?